# Sort using a field in an embedded doc in an array without considering other equivalent fields in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, database

I have collection called `Products`.
Documents of `Products` look like this:

```
{
    id: 123456,
    recommendationByCategory: [
        {   categoryId: a01,
            recommendation: 3
        },
        {
            categoryId: 0a2,
            recommendation: 8
        },
        {
            categoryId: 0b10
            recommendation: 99
        },
        {
            categoryId : 0b5
            recommendation: 1
        }
    ]
}
{
    id: 567890,
    recommendationByCategory: [
        {   categoryId: a7,
            recommendation: 3
        },
        {
            categoryId: 0a2,
            recommendation: 1
        },
        {
            categoryId: 0b10
            recommendation: 999
        },
        {
            categoryId : 0b51
            recommendation: 12
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to find all the docs that contain `categoryId: 0a2` in `recommendationByCategory`, but want to get *sorted* using the `recommendation` of the `category 0a2` **alone** in asc order. It must not consider `recommendations` of other `categoryId`. I need id: 567890 followed by id: 123456.
I *cannot* use aggregation. Is it possible using Mongodb/Mongoose? I tried giving sort option of `'recommendationByCategory.recommendation: 1'` but it's not working.

**Expected Query:** `db.collection('products').find({'recommendaionByCategory.categoryId': categoryId}).sort({'recommendationByCategory.recommendation: 1'})`

**Expected Result:**

```
[
    {doc with id:567890},
    {doc with id: 123456}
]
```

Comment: There's a pretty good chance you want to build a query with the [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/). Can you post what your query looks like here?

Comment: Can you post your expected result?

Comment: @broguinn Currently we are using aggregation pipeline with $unwind and $sort but we need to make it use simpler queries

Comment: @abdulbarik I have already added it in the question

Comment: What is the reason for moving away from aggregation framework using unwind and sort?

Comment: @notionquest Our lead engg. claims it to be resource intensive on Mongo instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot use mapReduce or the aggregation pipeline, there is no easy way to both search for the matching embedded document *and* sort on that document's prop.

I would recommend doing the find as you do above (note the typo in the find nested key), and then sorting in-memory:

```
const categoryId = '0a2';
const findRec = doc => doc.recommendationByCategory.find({ categoryId }).recommendation;

db.collection('products')
.find({'recommendationByCategory.categoryId': categoryId})
.then(docs => docs.sort((a, b) => findRec(a) < findRec(b));
```

In regard to the Aggregation Pipeline being resource-intensive: it is several orders of magnitude more efficient than a Map-Reduce query, and solves your particular issue. Either you accept that this task will be run at a certain cost and frequency, taking into account [Mongo's built-in caching](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/), or you restructure your document schema to allow you to make this query more efficiently.

Comment: This is the last resort